# Flutter Create Invite Link to edit List with others

Tags: database, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I'm working on create a ToDo App.

I want to implement a Feature where I can add different People to this ToDo List with a Link. I imagined that i have "Share Icon" that i can Press, get the Link for sharing this ToDo List inside the App with my Friends for example over WhatsApp. I know that for Share with Friends that there a package exists in the pub.dev.

For the Storage I use the Cloud_Firestore. My Idea was that i create for every user that joins  a own Collection that i then can convert into a Link, with the Link i can share then.

Can I implement the idea like this?
Does someone know if for the share ToDo List a package exists?
If not, how can i create this Feature to share the ToDo List with the Link?